# Is it possible to incorporate QGIS shapefile / polygon to XAMPP?

Tags: qgis, mysql, mariadb

I want to make a website using XAMPP but it must include a map of our city. I used QGIS to produce a shapefile of our city. I also want to use MySQL / MariaDB as the database but I don't know how to connect the map with XAMPP's MySQL / MariaDB.

What I want to make is a map that changes its colors based on the number of instances the data is called in the database. Just like a hot spot analysis. I was able to do it in QGIS but I do know what to do where to start in incorporating the map with XAMPP.